# Hardware acceleration doesn't seem to be working on an Nvidia GeForce 8800

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

So, I decided to ditch my old 11.10 Wubi install and make my install of 12.04 a fresh install that doesn't use Wubi. Unity 3D worked fine on 11.10 until NVidia sent out those botched drivers, but here on my current install, Unity 3D will kick me right back out to the login screen before it even loads anything. Which is puzzling, since my hardware is supposedly compatible:

[image: Unity_Support_Test results. Everything is greenlit.]

I seem to have similar problems with Gnome-Shell as well, which is puzzling. I'm guessing my problems with these stem from hardware acceleration not working properly, which is puzzling. Is there any reasons why hardware acceleration isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once when I had installed and the proprietary driver was not installed... Unity set itself to use Unity2D and stayed there even after installing the correct drivers.

I had to run the following command:

unity --reset

and then

unity --replace

Not sure if that will work for your particular case, but my card was a Geforce 8800 GTS 320.